# Rake Unit Testing : "False" being used for column "no"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rake

## Post :: Model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :name, :no, :num
end
```

## Posts.yml  under (test/fixtures/)

```
one:
  name: MyString
  body: MyString
  no: 1
  num: 2
```

On running, `rake test:units`, the following stack trace is generated

```
Error:
test_Post_for_correct_attributes(PostTest):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: table posts has no column named false: INSERT INTO "posts" ("name", "body", "false", "num", "created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('MyString', 'MyString', 1, 2, '2012-12-26 10:24:36', '2012-12-26 10:24:36', 980190962)
```

Now, here - the table field 'no' has been converted to 'false'. (which seems to be a problem since its being interpreted as FALSE and not as a object variable)

A bug with how it is converting the variables from yaml to object?

Rails version `Rails 3.2.9` and Ruby `ruby 1.9.3p194`

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8612

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems like bug to me since Rails should be able to pick up on that, especially since this is autogenerated. Anyway, as a temporary workout, you can use:

```
one:
  name: MyString
  body: MyString
  "no": 1
  num: 2
```

Comment: yes. This works. I have also added a github issue here https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8612